# Accessing states of parent application in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, state

I have several custom components all of which are included in the parent application.

When I try to change state from a custom component, I get an error saying "undefined state: state name". How do I change the state of the application from within a custom component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep your custom component from being tied to your application I would recommend having the component dispatch a custom event that the parent application listens for.  The parent application would then change its own state after receiving the event from the component.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The simple but wrong way:

```
(parent as __application-class__).state = "__state-name__"
```

replacing the terms with underlines with their appropriate names. but as wade pointed out, it's a clumsy, brittle way to do it. If your application is small and not going to be seen by other developers though this is fine.

The right way of doing this would be setting up your main application to change its own state in response to some condition or input such as an event fired by another component.